# Como cerrar un navbar con react al seleccionar una opcion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Tengo un problema con mi navbar. Y es que, cuando se le da click a cualquiera de las opciones este no cierra, y queda abierto. Se trabaja con React router dom y react respectivamente

```
const [isNavbarOpen, setIsNavbarOpen] = useState(false);

const toggleNavbar = () => {
    setIsNavbarOpen(!isNavbarOpen);
  };


<div>
      <Navbar color="faded" light className="navbar">
        <NavbarBrand href="/" className="me-auto">
          <h1 className="title1">
            InfoTPM
            <IconMaker className="IconMaker" />
          </h1>
        </NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarToggler onClick={toggleNavbar} className="botonDesplegable" />
        <Collapse isOpen={isNavbarOpen} navbar className="desplegable">
          <Nav navbar>
            {logged ? (
              user.usu_role === "user" || user.usu_role === "Driver" ? (
                <ul className="buttons">
                  <li key="Perfil">
                    <Link className="btn" to="/Perfil">
                      Perfil
                    </Link>
                    <div className="Divider" />
                  </li>
                  <li key="Lineas">
                    <Link className="btn" to="/Lines">
                      Lineas
                    </Link>
                    <div className="Divider" />
                  </li>
```

El código es mas largo pero solo coloco esa seccón para no llenar todo

Comment: Puedes insertar bloques de código interactivos de HTML, CSS y Javascript, incluso React. Hacerlo es buena idea ya que necesitamos ver un [mre].